# clear content : base layer doesn't match shown logcat for clearing webview contents in android

Tags: android-webview, loaddata

When I using webview.clearview() to clear the webview contents that loaded previously, LogCat shows text as

```
"05-21 13:39:48.730: V/webcore(28508): clear content : base layer doesn't match"
```

and my webview loading the same content repeatedly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `clearView()` API is a bit weird. If you want the webview to not show any content just call:

```
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```